# Mixed cut{after,before} keep line from fullcircle

Tags: metapost

I have a very simple code to get the angle from two vectors made of three points, that uses `cutafter` and `cutbefore`.

```
vardef arc(expr o,a,b) = 
  path c, d, e ;
  c = fullcircle scaled u shifted o ;
  d = c cutafter  (b -- o) -- o -- cycle ;
  e = d cutbefore (a -- o) -- o -- cycle ;
  e
enddef ;
```

It almost do the job:

[image]

As you can see on the previous picture, there is a tiny issue. The colored lines between `origin` and `point 0` of the `fullcircle`s used in the macro.

How can I get rid of it?

Here is a mwe, as requested by mickep,

```
path c ;
c = fullcircle scaled u xscaled 2 yscaled 2 ;
draw c withcolor lightgray ;
z[0] = point 1 of c;
z[1] = point 2 of c;
z[2] = point 4 of c;
z[3] = point -2 of c;

path arcs[] ;
arcs[0] = arc(origin,z0,z3) ;
arcs[1] = arc(origin,z0,z2) ;
arcs[2] = arc(origin,z0,z1) ;

fill arcs[0] scaled  1 withcolor .50[white,blue]  withpen pencircle scaled 0pt;
draw arcs[0] scaled  1 withcolor .75[white,blue]  withpen pencircle scaled .25pt ;
fill arcs[1] scaled .8 withcolor .50[white,green] withpen pencircle scaled 0pt;
draw arcs[1] scaled .8 withcolor .75[white,green] withpen pencircle scaled .25pt ;
fill arcs[2] scaled .6 withcolor .50[white,red]   withpen pencircle scaled 0pt;
draw arcs[2] scaled .6 withcolor .75[white,red]   withpen pencircle scaled .25pt ;

draw (origin -- z[0]) ;
draw (origin -- z[1]) ;
draw (origin -- z[2]) ;
draw (origin -- z[3]) ;
```

which produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: Can you please include the complete code to the example?

Comment: Of course! Here it is.

Comment: The `save` as shown in @mickep answer is important if you are going to use local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to cut both before and after in the same go. I have in the example below drawn the temporary graphs to show how they look. It seems to me that it is `f` (the blue one) and not `e` (the yellow one) that you want, but I might misunderstand your question.

```
\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
u:=4cm ;

vardef arc(expr o,a,b) = 
  save c, d, e, f ;
  path c, d, e, f ;
  c = fullcircle scaled u shifted o ;
  draw c withpen pencircle scaled 7 withcolor red ;
  d = c cutafter  (b -- o) -- o -- cycle ;
  draw d withpen pencircle scaled 5 withcolor green ;
  e = d cutbefore (a -- o) -- o -- cycle ;
  draw e withpen pencircle scaled 3 withcolor yellow ;
  f = (c cutafter (b -- o) cutbefore (a -- o)) -- o --cycle ;
  draw f withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor blue ;
  f
enddef ;

path c ;
c = fullcircle scaled 2u ;% xscaled 2 yscaled 2 ;
z[0] = point 1 of c;
z[3] = point -2 of c;

draw arc(origin,z0,z3) withpen pencircle scaled 0.5 withcolor 0.5[blue,white] ;

\stopMPpage
```

[image: parts of the circle]

Comment: This is interesting. Still learning a lot thanks to you! Do you know why it works when performing both cuts in one time but not in two separate operations like in my attempt?

Comment: Very good. Comment out the drawings, and draw the paths one by one, and you will see what happens. If not, ping me again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler version of `arc(o, a, b)` that avoids any local variables, and uses rotation to avoid the `cutbefore`.

```
vardef arc(expr o, a, b) =  % arc from a to b (produced) centred at o
  (fullcircle rotated angle (a-o) 
              cutafter (origin -- unitvector(b-o))
  ) scaled 2 length (a-o) shifted o
  enddef;
```